# plot an odd number of numpy arrays in subplots

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I have to visualize preliminary processing results, that only exist as numpy ndarrays. 
To do so, I am using pyplot (`plt`) from matplotlib and `imshow` + `subplots`.

```
fig, ((mb_arr, mk_arr),(k10_b, k10_l)) = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(16, 12))
mb_arr.imshow(mb_2014_array, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
mk_arr.imshow(mk_2014_array, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
k10_b.imshow(k10_build_array, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
k10_l.imshow(k10_lake_array, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
k10_f.imshow(k10_forest_array, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest');
```

However, I am stuck with four out of five results, because I can't get the fifth array printed in the setup of subplots. Below is the code I am using at the moment, and the error here is:

```
--> fig, ((mb_arr, mk_arr),(k10_b, k10_l), (k10_f, )) = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(16, 12))

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

How do I have to specify, that the last row in the 3 x 2 grid will contain only one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used http://www.python-course.eu/matplotlib_multiple_figures.php

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 5):
    plt.subplot(3,2,i)
    plt.plot(np.sin(x))
plt.subplot(3,2,(5,6))
plt.plot(np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

and with `imshow` and `cmap` and `interpolation`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
x = np.random.randint(0, 255, [10, 20])
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 5):
    plt.subplot(3,2,i)
    plt.imshow(x, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.subplot(3,2,(5,6))
plt.imshow(x, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen the course and the examples as well. Using `subplot` I can arrange the different arrays. Any chance for a solution using the `subplots` method?

Comment: Sorry I realized that too late. Your solution works for sure. Would you know how to get it to work with `subplots`?